# What to do with limits of infinite sequences with trigonometric functions?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the sequence
$$ a_n = \left (\frac {1+\cos (n)}{2+\cos (n)}\right)^{2n-\log(n)} $$
If Cauchy's convergence criterion is used (square root of $a_n$ - the exponent approaches 2 as x approaches infinity), it all comes down to the fraction.By Cauchy's criterion, we have to find out if the limit of $ \sqrt{a_n}$ is less than 1, equal to 1 or greater than 1.Since $cosx$ can be anything from $[-1, 1]$, is this limit solvable?In this particular sequence, the limit could be less than 1 (it's either $0$, $\frac{1}{4}$ or $\frac{4}{9}$).My book says that this sequence converges while wolframalpha says otherwise, I'm not sure who is right.

Comment: Do you mean $$a_n=\left(\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2+\cos(x)}\right)^{2x+\log(x)}$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, I will edit it, except the + log(x), it's minus.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
0<\frac {1+\cos n}{2+\cos n}<\frac23\quad\forall n\in\Bbb N.
$$

Comment: With the square, it's 4/9 (right side).What about cases when we can't say what the limit is?For example, in one case we get that the limit is less than one, and in the second case we get that the limit is greater than one (since trigonometric functions can have different values)?

Comment: First of all, you do not know that the limit of $a_n^{1/n}$ exists (in fact, I am pretty sure that it does not exist.) All we can say is that $\limsup a_n^{1/n}\le4/9$. As for the rest of the question, you should give specific examples.